# Why does my USB drive appeared split in two?

Tags: usb, mount

I put a 64GB Kingston USB key in one of the USB ports on the Pi.

It has been recognized and mounted automatically and I am able to write files, but why, in the MEDIA directory, has KINGSTON has been split between KINGSTON and KINGSTON_,  one with 16 GB and the other 48 GB?

When the first is full what will happen, as my code mentions only" /media/KINGSTON"?

Comment: If you could run `mount` and `sudo fdisk -l` and post the output to http://pastebin.net that would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it is due to filesystem type limitation when automounted. If the key is empty so wiping all the data inside is not a problem (thanks for the comment *RPi Awesomeness*), you can create an ext4 filesystem with

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdNN
```

where NN is the device name. 
You must first dismount the already mounted drives with either:

```
umount /dev/sdNN
```

or

```
umount /directory mount point
```

for each one.

Comment: This *is* a very useful answer, but just as a heads-up to people who aren't as computer/Linux-savy, formatting (making a filesystem as suggested here) ***will*** wipe your data. Just a heads up, if you're doing this, make sure to back up any data you don't want to lose. Great job on the answer.

Comment: Also it will be /dev/sdNN. (/dev/hdNN is for legacy IDE drivers only since the kernel moved to the (S)ATA modules by default.)